# Alternative for Kentico 12 Message Board in Kentico 13

Tags: kentico, kentico-mvc, kentico-kontent

I am migrating Kentico 12 to 13. I found that in Kentico 12 project I have CMS.MessageBoard.dll which is not available in Kentico 13.

Is there any alternative for the same?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in Kentico Xperience 13 to replicate that.  However a custom module could be created or reverse engineered based on the version 12 instance. OR you could look for a third party option to add/integrate with Kentico Xperience 13. I know they aren't great options, but they are an options.

Comment: Or, integrate some third party tools for discussions/message boards. Or leverage the custom tables module to store the data and implement custom logic to display and save the messages into custom modules.